# How to access Pseudo Elements (:before, :after, etc) or Pseudo Classes (:hover, :visited, etc) using MSHTML?

Tags: .net, css, internet-explorer, mshtml

I'm parsing a document with MSHTML and I need to determine the Pseudo Elements in the document. Right now I have a reference to an IHTMLElement in .net code and I need to determine if this element has pseudo elements such as "before" or "after" applied to it.

For example, in the example document code below, I have a reference to the clearfloat div (as an IHTMLElement, from my MSHTML .net code) and I need to determine what the pseudo element's "after" style is. How can I do this with MSHTML?

```
<style type="text/css">
  .clearfloat:after 
   {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    content: ".";
   }
</style>

<div class="clearfloat">
    Some text...
</div>
```

More common are Pseudo Classes, such as ":hover". I also cannot figure out how to determine :hover style. I really need Pseudo Elements, but I'm hoping that if I can figure out how to access Pseudo Classes it might yield a clue about accessing Pseudo Elements.

Does anyone know how access Pseudo Classes or Elements with MSHTML?

Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for knowing the difference between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes. These little things make me happy for some reason.

Comment: Actually, pseudo-elements should be ::before and ::after. **** Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all style sheets in IHTMLDocument2 interface:
Reference: Microsoft.mshtml (Or use reflection)

```
WebBrowser browser;
...
IHTMLDocument2 doc2=browser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
if(doc2!=null)
{
    Int32 index=doc2.styleSheets.length-1;
    IHTMLStyleSheet style = doc2.styleSheets.item(index);

    Int32 ruleIndex=style.rules.length-1;
    String selector = style.rules.item(ruleIndex).selectorText;
    MessageBox(String.Format("Last selector in last style sheet: {0}",selector));
}
```